# Unable to display contact list in Android Studio using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display my contact list for my mobile application. I have already connected the database and I figured that there is no problem with the database since I can add new contact but I am unable to display the list. I use RecyclerView which I already created Adapter class, item layout and model for.

- Adapter class - contAdapter.java
- item layout - item.xml
- Model - Contact
- RecyclerView Layout - contactList.xml
- contactList - to bind recyclerview with adapter

I wish to see the list of contact added to the database to be displayed on the screen but I have been stuck here for quite some time since I cannot figure out what the problem is :(

Here is my Contact Model:

```
public Contact() {

}

public Contact(String contName, String contNumber) {
this.contName = contName;
this.contNumber = contNumber;
}

public String getContName() {
return contName;
}

public void setContName(String contName) {
this.contName = contName;
}

public String getContNumber() {
return contNumber;
}

public void setContNumber(String contNumber) {
this.contNumber = contNumber;
}
```

`contactList.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="25dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`contactList.java`:

```
    package com.example.lucentproj;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull; 
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; 
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; 
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;`
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class contactList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    contAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Contact> list;
    FirebaseUser user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.contList);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contact");
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new contAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

    Contact contact = dataSnapshot.getValue(Contact.class);
    list.add(contact);

    }
    adapter.updateList(list);
  }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

   }
});
}
}
```

`item.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp" app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    
    
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth_italic"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
    
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cCall"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/call" />
    
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cEdit"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`contAdapter`:

```
package com.example.lucentproj;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.TextView; 
import androidx.annotation.NonNull; 
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class contAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<contAdapter.ViewHolder> {Context context;

    ArrayList<Contact> list;

public contAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Contact cont = list.get(position);
    holder.cname.setText(cont.getContName());
    holder.cnum.setText(cont.getContNumber());

}

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView cname, cnum;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contName);
        cnum =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.contNumber);
    }
}
    public void updateList(ArrayList<Contact> list){
    this.list=list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: My application can be launched successfully without any errors but the contact list is not displayed. It will only show blank page

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

**You are not updating list in Adaptor**

*Please add this method in your adaptor class -*

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Contact> list){
   this.list=list;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And replace this line from your contactList activity to **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** --> **adapter.updateList(list);**

**contactList.java**

```
   package com.example.lucentproj;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull; 
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; 
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; 
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; 
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;`
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class contactList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    contAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Contact> list;
    FirebaseUser user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.contList);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contact");
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         Contact contact = dataSnapshot.getValue(Contact.class);
         list.add(contact);
      }
    }

    adapter = new contAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

    Contact contact = dataSnapshot.getValue(Contact.class);
    list.add(contact);

    }
    adapter.updateList(list);
  }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

   }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: I have made the adjustment but it still not displaying the data :(

Comment: update the question with your changes.

Comment: check updated Answer I have modified contactList.java